# how to compare two lists in different functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-views

I am making a Django web Application and i am facing a problem in comparing two different lists in different functions

```
def test(request,slug):
    n=request.user
    choice=TestOptions.objects.filter(choice=slug).first()
    que=questions.objects.filter(Subject=choice)  
    question=[]
 
    un=['a','b','c','d','e']
    
    for q in que:
        if q not in question:
            question.append(q)
        else:
            continue
    sampling = random.sample(question, 5)
    print("--------------SamPLING111")
    print(sampling)
    print("--------------SamPLING111")
    correctAnswers=[]
    for j in sampling:
          
            correctAnswers.append(j.answer)

    marks(correctAnswers)
    d = dict(zip(un,sampling))
    return render(request,"code/test.html",{'questions':d})

def acceptAnswer(request):
    answers=[]
    if request.method=="POST":
        answers.append(request.POST['a'])
        answers.append(request.POST['b'])
        answers.append(request.POST['c'])
        answers.append(request.POST['d'])
        answers.append(request.POST['e'])

        score(answers)
    return render(request,"code/dub.html")

def marks(correct):
  list1=[]
  l1=correct

def score(and):
  list2=[]
  l2=ans
```

function test is passing a list and function acceptAnswer is passing another list my job is to compare those two lists

how can I compare l1 and l2?

Comment: You need them to exist at the same time first.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: well actually that's now possible because it is actually getting values different functions in Django so they exist separately

Comment: How you can do what you want to do is a bit separate from if you should or if the way you can do it is a good one which will depend on what exactly you're trying to do and why. What is the significance of these lists? Where do they come from? They currently live in different scopes and so don't exist at the same time. You could make them global but that is likely a terrible idea. Maybe they should both be member variables of a class that holds both functions, maybe you should rethink your functions or the flow of your app to make it easier.

Comment: @DavidOldford see i have made all the possible changes now please look into it

Comment: Could you pass marks(correctAnswers) as a parameter of your acceptAnswer() function? You could then compare them.

Comment: no thats not how it works in Django

Comment: could you describe what exactly your web app is supposed to be doing? where does the value que come from? what are the functions marks and score supposed to do? It looks to me like you're creating short multiple choice tests and then having someone do a test and marking it. You should probably be storing your state about the test in a database.

Comment: Looking at your profile I'm assuming this is part of a university assignment. Your issues have to do with both how variables are scoped and how web applications work. There are a number of different ways to store persistent state for a web application for the problem I think you're trying to solve using a database is likely the best one, but if you are doing a web apps course you may not have covered that material in which case I'd expect your prof would have included something in the assignment or talked about something in class they expect you to use until you get to databases and ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100 percent what you are trying to do with these lists, but in order to compare them I would just return them. Here is a quick example:

```
def marks(correct):
    list1 = []
    l1 = correct
    return l1

def score(answer):
    list2 = []
    l2 = answer
    return l2
    
numbers = [1,2,3]
numbers2 = [1,2,3]
numbers3 = [3,4,5]

print(marks(numbers) == score(numbers2)) # True
print(marks(numbers2) == score(numbers3)) # False
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: no it won't help me see my new changes in the question

Answer (score 1):

Rather than continue with comments I figured I'd elaborate in an answer though it isn't an exact answer to your question I think it is the real answer.

You really have two issues. One is a design issue ie how to make your program work correctly and the other is an implementation issue about the scope of variables and how to deal with it.

I can see in your profile you're a university student and given the nature of the code it seems very likely you're writing your web app for the purposes of learning maybe even an assignment.

If you were doing this outside of a university I'd expect you were seeking practitioner type skills in which case I'd suggest the answer would be to design your application the way Django expects you to, which I would say would translate into storing state information in a database.

If this is a lab however you may not have covered databases yet. Labs sometimes have students doing silly things because they can't teach everything at the same time. So your Prof may not expect you to use a database yet.

Inside a web application you have to consider that the web is request response and that you can get requests from a lot of different sources so you have state management concerns that classical desktop applications don't have. Who is supposed to see these tests and who is supposed to see the marks and what is the order these things happen? Should anyone be able to create a test? Should anyone be able to take a test? You might not care yet, eventually you'll want to care about sessions. If people are taking their own tests you could store data in a user session but then other people wouldn't see those tests. Generally the correct way to store this sort of state is in a database where you can access it according to what you know about the current request. If this is some sort of basic intro app your Prof may be happy with you doing something kludgy for now.